# How can I write at the top of an XML file with XML::Writer

Tags: xml, perl

I create an XML file with [XML::Writer](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/XML::Writer) in Perl and I would want that each times I call my script it writes the new XML file at the beginning of the old file. I know how to write a line at the beginning of a file, but with XML::Writer I can't find how to do that.

```
my $output = new IO::File(">>tmp.xml");
my $writer = new XML::Writer( 
OUTPUT      => $output,
DATA_INDENT => 3,             # indentation, trois espaces
DATA_MODE   => 1,             # changement ligne.
);
```

That's the beginning of my script which writes the xml file.

**Edit**:
I actually do a changelog.xml which looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="changelog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>

<root text="MultiDiag">
<version number="V: 7.07.10.0" date="Release date (Fri Oct  7 14:44:52 2016)">
Things
</version>
</root>
```

What I want is that each day, the new changelog is write at the top of the old one like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="changelog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<root text="MultiDiag">
<version number="V: 7.07.10.0" date="Release date (The new one)">
Things
</version>
<version number="V: 7.07.10.0" date="Release date (The old one)">
Things
</version>
</root>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. Can you please include an example of what you want your output to be like? You can [edit] your question. Usually there is one XML data structure in one file. There is always an element around everything. It's not clear what you mean by writing to the top.

Comment: That's almost by definition invalid XML, because you won't have the right root tags.

Comment: Please don't use indirect object notation. At some point you will trip over a bug that it causes and will waste hours trying to find it. Instead of `new IO::File(..)` and `new XML::Writer(...)`, you should use `IO::File->new(...)` and `XML::Writer->new(...)`.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the tips, I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to not let XML::Writer write to a file directly. Instead, you can set `OUTPUT` to `"self"` and then use the [`$writer->to_string` method](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/XML::Writer#OUTPUT) to get a string with the rendered output.

After that, all you need to do is follow [this example from perlfaq5](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change-delete-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file) on how to write to the beginning of a file. You basically read in your existing file line by line, and print it back to a new file. If you're at line 1 (`$.` is the current line number being read), you print the XML from `$writer`. Then you move/rename your temporary new file over the old one.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::File;
use XML::Writer;

my $writer = XML::Writer->new( 
    OUTPUT      => 'self',
    DATA_INDENT => 3,             # indentation, trois espaces
    DATA_MODE   => 1,             # changement ligne.
);

# ... put in your data

# open the old file and a temporary new file
open my $in,  '<',  'tmp.xml'  or die "Can't read old file: $!";
open my $out, '>', 'tmp.xml.new' or die "Can't write new file: $!";

# read from the old file
while( <$in> ) {
    # write the XML into the first line
    print $out $writer->to_string if $. == 1;

    # write the rest of the file line by line
    print $out $_;
}
close $in; 
close $out;

# replace the old file with the new file
rename 'tmp.xml.new', 'tmp.xml';
```

Comment: Thx simbabque it works perfectly. The "OUTPUT => `self`" was what I need.